# FPS drop in every game that I played recently

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, fps

Ok, this is what happened to my laptop, 
I have a Asus N76VZ laptop.
Windows 8, Downgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
8GB RAM , GT650m 4GB Graphic Card.
i7 processor.

I would say a mid end gaming for myself,
I play most of steam game without problem all the time
etc : cs:go, BF3, Dota2, L4D2, Hon, LoL, ...
I usually play with max/high setting in dota2, including v-sync on, my fps always stay at 60fps regarding fighting scene or not. same goes with other game. 
and like wise for cs:go, L4D2, I try play without vsync on, I would get about 100-200fps.
My temp always stay around 60'C or 70.
Not a problem with my heat sink i believe.
I clean my laptop every week.

So recently there is Nvidia graphic driver updates, So I did update it, to keep drivers up to date,
but ended up, after updates, all my game fps drop! like crazy, with or without vsync, 
all my fps goes like 10-20fps in low setting or resolution, unable to play at all.
So, I tried revert my drivers, back to previous version, which do a clean re-installation it.
still doesn't work out. 
I keep trying by downgrading the grahpic card driver from the latest to the oldest version.
Still doesn't work out. 
I tried reformat my laptop and reinstall everything again, none seem to work
I did try to change all the setting about graphic or in game, as I myself a gamer too.
So what do you think is wrong with my laptop ? :(

Thank you so much! if you guys would be able to help me out!

Comment: Please explain precisely what you mean by " it still doesn't work out." this information is important so I can answer the question. It would be appreciated if you updated the question when you did this.  Of course if you have already reinstalled Windows, and you still have the problem described, that is an indication this is a hardware issue.  I would assume when you reinstalled Windows you didn't use the same version of the driver that you thought were the problem.

Comment: I mean I have Windows clean re-installed and the graphic card been up to date, doesn't fix the problem that fps drop in all my game.
Its been 2 days now, ever since I reinstall windows.
I also tried to use older version of the graphic card, still not not fixing the problem. I tried a lot of different version too.

Thank you so much for the reply!

Comment: If you select a difference version and select the clean installation option, does this problem still exist, if so then that is a guaranteed confirmation you have a hardware problem.

Comment: Yes still exist, What could possibly be the problem? :(

Comment: Do you have the Intel display drivers installed?  Did you install the Nvidia drivers offered by ASUS or Nvidia?

Comment: Oh yes, I have intel display driver installed, and I only installed the driver from the Nvidia, but didn't try the one that offered from Asus. o_o

Comment: You need to uninstall the Intel display drivers.  You have a dedicated graphic cards since you have a `Nvidia GT650m`, based on what you describe, I am going to guess your performance problems were originally caused by the Intel display drivers being installed automatically by Windows at some point.

Comment: So I have to uninstall the Intel Driver and just install the latest version of Nvidia driver ?